# PostgreSQL compare with substring doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, select, substring, inner-join

I want to select from 2 table where 2nd id is equal with first 4 character from first id

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, substring(a.my_id from 1 for 4)::integer as number
   FROM table1 as a
INNER Join table2 as b ON(b.id_2=number) where my_id = 101
                                 ^
It produces an error here        |
```

ERROR:  column "number" does not exist

SQL state: 42703

Character: 189

Comment: Aliases from the `SELECT` list don't work in `FROM` list. Move `substring(a.my_id from 1 for 4)::integer` to your `ON` condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an alias like that, you need a derived table:

```
select *
from (
   SELECT t1.*, 
          substring(t1.my_id::text from 1 for 4)::integer as number
   FROM table1 t1
) as a 
inner join table2 as b ON (b.id_2 = a.number) 
where my_id = 101
```

Storing a number that is used as a foreign key as a part in a varchar column is a really, really ugly design. That number should be a column of its own in table1.

Comment: In this case it gives me  ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry in subquery for table "a" inside 2nd select

Comment: @Alex: sorry too much copy & paste (but with a little bit of thinking you could have fixed that yourself)

Comment: however it did not solve my problem (       function pg_catalog.substring (integer, integer, integer) does not exist

Comment: @Alex: What datatype is `my_id`?

Comment: @Alex: you don't like reading manuals, do you? The substring is a function that works on strings not on numbers. See my edit. Do re-think your design. Using only parts of a number as a reference to another table is absolutely insane.